# Spacy beam search memory leak?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, beam-search

When I use spacy's beam search, there will be a memory leak problem, how can I solve it? The code that causes the memory leak is as follows:

```
beams = nlp.entity.beam_parse(docs, beam_width=beam_width, beam_density=beam_density)
```

Comment: You may wish to open an issue here https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed as of spacy v2.2.4.

Comment: My spacy version is v2.3.2